# What is this so used as?

Tags: inversion, so

> They acquired Tai-me, the sacred Sun Dance doll, from that moment the object and symbol of their worship, and **so** shared in the divinity of the sun.

<sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

I do not know what this so is used as. Is it used as a conjunction denoting an effect, or used as kind of a complement serving the purpose of so in the sentence "it seems so"?

If it is the latter, is so inverted in some way? Would the uninverted version be "and shared so in the..."?

Comment: No, it's not a conjunction. The conjunction "and" marks the coordination relation and "so" is a connective adverb functioning as a modifier within the second coordinate "and so shared in the divinity of the sun". Its meaning is "therefore", as a result".

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is a conjunction and means *for that reason*.

and for that reason shared in the divinity of the sun

> [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/so): for that reason; therefore:
>   *My knee started hurting so I stopped running.*
>   *I was lost so I bought a street map.*

Comment: Whew, finally found my password. I thought it meant something like "...and share as the object and symbol of their worship in the divinity of the sun. Is it wrong?

Comment: If you take out the inessential phrases, you are left with "They acquired Tai-me and **so** [for that reason] shared in the divinity of the sun."

Comment: Is share in this sentence an intransitive verb?

Comment: @whitedevil Yes, it's intransitive _to share **in_ as opposed _to share sth._

Comment: Two conjunctions cannot normally appear consecutively. In "and so", it is "and" that marks the coordination relation and "so" is a modifier within the second coordinate. The meaning of "so" here is "therefore, as a result". In traditional grammar "so" is treated a coordinator in something like, "It was raining, so the match was cancelled", though some modern grammars treat it as a preposition in such examples